# How to remove white border/bar that shows iPhone battery at top ionic v1 app?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, ionic-framework

I am trying to migrate a IOS Cordova HTML5, JS project into Ionic v1.

I finally got it working, but there is a big white border at the very top html page that allows users to see the battery and other things on the iPhone.

The bar causes a ton of aspect ratio and resolution problems and I need to get it out of the mix entirely.

This did not exist in my original IOS Cordova HTML5, JS project and i am guessing something in the Ionic v1 framework automatically provides this white bar at the top.

The problem is, this creates a ton of problems for my app and I need to completely eliminate it.

Inserting the following code does not eliminate this.

```
<ion-header no-border>
```

I made a test project that just contains some text to see if the white border/battery bar is there too and it is.

The sample code from the index.html is shown below. If I can solve the problem here, I can solve it for my actual project.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
 <!--   <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width"> -->
    <title>MyApp</title>

    <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"> 

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
 <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script> 
 
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
 // Wait for device API libraries to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    // Cordova is ready
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
     }
</script>
  </head>
  <body style="background-color: black" onLoad="onDeviceReady()">
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my Config.xml

```html
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="local.app.my" ios-CFBundleVersion="0.0.1" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>MyApp</name>
    <description>An awesome Ionic/Cordova app.</description>
    <author email="hi@ionicframework" href="http://ionicframework.com/">Ionic Framework Team</author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://ionic.local/*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
    <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
    <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300" />
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="mdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="hdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <splash density="land-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
        <icon height="57" src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" />
        <icon height="114" src="resources/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
        <icon height="40" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png" width="40" />
        <icon height="80" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@3x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="50" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50.png" width="50" />
        <icon height="100" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />
        <icon height="60" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60.png" width="60" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="180" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
        <icon height="72" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72.png" width="72" />
        <icon height="144" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
        <icon height="76" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76.png" width="76" />
        <icon height="152" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
        <icon height="167" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167" />
        <icon height="29" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29" />
        <icon height="58" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
        <icon height="87" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />
        <icon height="1024" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-1024.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="1136" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="1334" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-667h.png" width="750" />
        <splash height="2208" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-736h.png" width="1242" />
        <splash height="1242" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" />
        <splash height="1536" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@~ipadpro.png" width="2732" />
        <splash height="768" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@~ipadpro.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="1024" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />
        <splash height="960" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="480" src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" width="320" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~universal~anyany.png" width="2732" />
    </platform>
    <preference name="orientation" value="landscape" />
    <engine name="ios" spec="^4.4.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="^1.1.4" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="^4.0.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="^1.3.1" />
    <plugin name="ionic-plugin-keyboard" spec="^2.2.1" />
</widget>
```

Any help, advice, or suggestions at how I can eliminate this top battery bar border area universally from within the config.xml and/or from within the index.html would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "top battery bar border area" is called the statusbar and you can either use [`cordova-plugin-statusbar`](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar) to hide it at runtime like this:

**Installation:**

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-statusbar --save
```

**Then call `.hide()` in the device-ready callback:**

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
  StatusBar.hide();
}
```

If you want it also to be hidden at startup you have to use `cordova-custom-config` like this:

**Installation:**

```
cordova plugin add cordova-custom-config --save
```

**And add the following to your `config.xml` as children of the [`<platform name="ios">`](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-custom-config) tag:**

```
<config-file parent="UIStatusBarHidden" platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist">
  <true/>
</config-file>
<config-file parent="UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance" platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist">
  <false/>
</config-file>
```

Comment: You sir, are a Godsend! Thank you so much! That did it!

Comment: No problem! I‘m glad I could help you out :)

Comment: Finally something which actually worked with my old ionic v1